# Showing lat, long points from MongoDB on a webmap

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, leaflet, gis

I have locations (lat, long) in a MongoDB. How would I go about to show them (preferably real-time) on a web page? The locations are sent to the db from an app, and from the app we can see real-time locations on a map. But I need to make these points available for regular web users. At the moment we can also download all the points as a geojson file. Dev stack is MongoDB, React Native, Node (jade, express).

Comment: The locations are shown succesfully from within the React Native app. It's just that I need to show the same locations for regular web users.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to show them in a map on a screen in react-native the react-native docs suggest using https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps to display the lat longs as markers on the map.

I can't tell by your question, but have you had success getting the locations to your react-native application?